# The output becomes weird after using the js locally

Tags: javascript, latex, plotly, mathjax, plotly.js

I am trying to use latex with plotly. After reading about the usage I came across this code:

```js
<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']], processEscapes: true}});</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML%2CSafe.js&#038;ver=4.1'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [1, 4, 9, 16],
  name: '$\\alpha_{1c} = 352 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}$',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [0.5, 2, 4.5, 8],
  name: '$\\beta_{1c} = 25 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}$',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {title: '$\\sqrt{(n_\\text{c}(t|{T_\\text{early}}))}$'},
  yaxis: {title: '$d, r \\text{ (solar radius)}$'}
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
</script>
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%"></div>
```

It is working fine. But when I downloaded the js files and tried to use then locally, the result is weird. Have a look:

[image: output image]

I have just changed these lines:

```
<script src="MathJax.js"></script>
<script src="plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

And this things went somewhere else.
Please guide me what I can do. I am using Plotly example from here:  https://plotly.com/javascript/LaTeX/

I hope to get response for the query.

Comment: Please can anyone try this and let me know what I should try to get the improved output?

Comment: Looks like you're missing parts of MathJax. MathJax consists of many more files than MathJax.js. Check docs.mathjax.org for how to install it per

Comment: Can you tell me what part I am missing? Please let me know. I want my application to run offline.

Comment: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html is the documentation's starting point.